# SQL Query with Count

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have the following tables:

**list**

- id - key
- name

**item**

- id - key
- name

**list_item**

- list_id - foreign key to list table
- item_id - foreign key to item table

I have the following query:

```
SELECT l.id, l.name
FROM list l, list_item li
WHERE l.id = li.list_id
```

I want to add to the result set, the count of items in the list.  How do I do this?

Comment: have you tried adding `COUNT()` to your query? Also please add some sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT l.id, l.name, COUNT(li.item_id) AS item_count 
FROM list l
LEFT JOIN list_item ON l.id = li.list_id
GROUP BY l.id
```

Comment: Shouldn't `l.name` be part of the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: `l.id` is the key of the `list`, why should `l.name` be part of the GROUP BY clause?

Comment: Seems to be valid in MySQL (but SQL Server complains that all columns other than those on which aggregate functions are applied, must be in the GROUP BY list). Sorry for false alarm!

Comment: @Vikdor Yes, you are right, this is MySQL special thing. Your alarm make sense if this is not MySQL :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SUM(l.id = li.list_id)
```

Comment: Did you mean to say `COUNT` instead of `SUM`?

Comment: I think `SUM` will work just fine here, `COUNT` should work as well but SUM is much more flexible...